# ProcessBuilder: Resultant process hangs in java in windows

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am facing some weird problem while executing external processes in Java.
When i try to run the process using the Process Builder. The process doesn't execute that moment. However, as soon as I stop the Java program, the process executes and the results are displayed.
Anyone has any ideas regarding such behavior.

Below is my code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", jarFileLocation,
                        fileEntry.getAbsolutePath(), commonFileLocation).redirectError(new File("C:/Users/Desktop/log.txt"));;
                pb.start();
```

I am redirecting the errors of the subprocess if any to a file 'log.txt'.

Comment: I believe you have a typo over here: `fileEntry.getAbsolutePath(), .commonFileLocation` (mind the dot after comma).

Comment: How exactly do you detect that "process hangs" and how do you run the parent process? Say, the process or your IDE may cache its output and display it only when cache is full or the process is terminated.

Comment: @yeputons: Edited. The problem is something else. I am using process builder to run a jar file that parses a file and generates code. However, when the Builder is run, the code doesn't generate untill i  manaully aborted the process. It seems that the Process builder is waiting for some other process to complete. I am running it in the eclipse.

Comment: How do you check that the process is not running? Task manager in Windows, `top`/`htop` in Linux, something else? What process name are you looking for? Does the problem persist if you try to run some other program, not `java`, e.g. `bash -c "echo foo"`?